# grabar un valor null en una base de datos a traves de php

Tags: php, mysql

muchas gracias por la ayuda, tengo que grabar en una base de datos este formulario en el cual contiene valores null, graba el resto de los valores bien saldo los null que no los cambia en al base. copio el codigo

```
<?php
$registro='168';
$null=null;
$caja="5";
echo'
<form method="POST" action="d.php">
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="entregado" value='.'no'.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="fecha_entrega_sobre" value='.$null.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_caja" value='.$caja.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_usuario_entrega_sobre" value='.$null.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_sobre" value='.$registro.'>                                      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm" name = "desarchiva_sobre" value = '.$registro.'>Desarchivar</button>
</form>';   


    if(isset($_POST['desarchiva_sobre'])){// FUNCION PARA ARCHIVAR SOBRES

        $campos=array(); 
        foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
        {
            if($k != "modifica"){
                if($k != "desarchiva_sobre"){

                    if ($v !=""){
                        $campos[]="$k='$v'";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        include 'abrir_conexion.php';
        $consulta = $conexion -> query ("UPDATE sobre SET ".implode(", ", $campos)." WHERE id_sobre = '{$_POST['id_sobre']}' ") or die ("Ha fallado la conexión1");
        }
?>
```

Comment: Imprime en pantalla esta parte del código para que revises qué es lo que estás mandando a ejecutar realmente: `UPDATE sobre SET ".implode(", ", $campos)." WHERE id_sobre = '{$_POST['id_sobre']}'` Si todo está bien ahí, confirma que esas columnas aceptan realmente valores `NULL`.

Comment: Para que el campo sea null, es necesario que el `$v` no vaya con comillas. Es lo mismo que para un entero. En tu caso es muy posible que esté guardando una cadena con el texto `null` en lugar del NULL que quieres guardar

Comment: Hola Jakala, muchas gracias por tu comentario, si he probado que si le saco las dobles comillas al valor $v, me graba el valor null pero no me graba el resto por ejemplo el texto "no" del primer imput y tampoco los campos numericos, como puedo hacer para que funcione para todo?

Comment: Parece también que estás implementando una lógica enrevesada para resolver algo simple. Lo digo por los tres `if` que veo dentro de tu `foreach`. ¿Podrías explicar qué intentas con eso? Quizá haya una mejor forma de asignar los valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se guarde en la base de datos valores `NULL` (siempre y cuando el campo en la tabla lo permita), haría el siguiente cambio:

Esto:

```
if ($v !="") {
    $campos[]="$k = '$v'";
}
```

Por esto:

```
if ($v !="") {
    $campos[]="$k = '$v'";
} else {
    $campos[]="$k = NULL";
}
```

Lo que quedaría algo como:

```
<?php
$registro='168';
$null=null;
$caja="5";
echo'
<form method="POST" action="d.php">
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="entregado" value='.'no'.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="fecha_entrega_sobre" value='.$null.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_caja" value='.$caja.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_usuario_entrega_sobre" value='.$null.'>
    <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center"  name="id_sobre" value='.$registro.'>                                      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm" name = "desarchiva_sobre" value = '.$registro.'>Desarchivar</button>
</form>';   

if (isset($_POST['desarchiva_sobre'])) {// FUNCION PARA ARCHIVAR SOBRES
    $campos=array(); 
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
        if($k != "modifica") {
            if($k != "desarchiva_sobre") {
                if ($v !="") {
                    $campos[]="$k = '$v'";
                } else {
                    $campos[]="$k = NULL";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    include 'abrir_conexion.php';
    $consulta = $conexion -> query ("UPDATE sobre SET ".implode(", ", $campos)." WHERE id_sobre = '{$_POST['id_sobre']}' ") or die ("Ha fallado la conexión1");
}
?>
```

Es un poco agarrada de los pelos para mi gusto, pero puede funcionar. Te invito a leer más sobre MySQLi, concretamente [MySQLi::prepare en la documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: hola Roxguel una excelente idea!!! muchas gracias por tu ayuda. un gran abrazo!